# Trying to animate a graph

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to animate a graph in javascript and html5 canvas.

If you have time to look at my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/herrturtur/MuLKE/3/), maybe you can tell me what I'm doing wrong with regards to the recalculate function.

I'm not exactly sure what is happening, which is why I put great effort into the fiddle to share with you. But I can tell you that the draw function (mostly responsible for drawing the graph's tickmarks) works fine by itself, but as soon as I call on draw repeatedly, no graph shows up at all.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What's the problem with the recalculate function?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I hope this is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

well, i'm not sure exactly what you expect to see, but... you had:

```
markIntervals(hour, 10);
markIntervals(day, 20);
```

..but no function for "markIntervals".  You meant "markInterval".  Fixing that typo let's your tick marks show up, even with the setInterval uncommented. I don't see where animation comes into play, but I hope that helped.

Comment: Animation comes into play when you move the slider. The tickmarks should move closer together or farther apart, depending on the direction you're moving the slider in.

Comment: I see what you are saying. A couple things:

Comment: sorry i couldn't type what I had to in the "5 minute" window SO give me (...very stupid).  ...I see what you are saying. A couple things: 1) You should probably just redraw when something changes (like put it in the recalc function). 2) There is a bug in the markInterval() function in your for loop conditions. It is never getting in there after the slider changes.  3) Your line setInterval('draw()', 60) should be setInterval(function() { draw(); }, 60);